# How to add a loading image in my frame?

Tags: java, swing

I have a made a small game in Java and when I open it using a JAR file, I have taken a frame where I want to put a "loading bar". How can I add the loading image to the frame?

Comment: What have you tried? Show us some code. SO is not a place, where you state a problem and get code in return. Show us your code, ask exact question about things you do not understand and we will try to help you.

Comment: Take a look at [Splash screens in java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html) if it's of interest.

Comment: [How to Use Progress Bars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html)

Comment: I have corrected capitalization mistakes in the content and have removed the language name from title as it is not required due to presence of tags. Please avoid using *help request* statements as they are also not required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `JProgressBar` if you can track how much it is loaded.
If can't track it then simply add a `JLabel` with `GIF` icon of loading animations (easily available on the web)

Comment: *"If can't track it then Simply.."*  ..call [`setIndeterminate(true)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JProgressBar.html#setIndeterminate-boolean-) ..